# Possible cause for corrupted images (colored stripe with dots in pictures)?

Tags: artifacts, data-corruption

I've noticed the below artifact/data corruption (colored stripe with dots) in a small handful of my photos, and I'm trying to figure out the cause. Is it the camera (Nikon d90)? Could it be the SD card or my storage device? I suspect it is not the storage (either SD or SSD), because it happens in the identical location in different photos.

[image]

Comment: What format is this? NEF or JPEG?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen i believe it was a raw image, though it's been a while.

Answer (score 2):

If the location is really identical, or a few locations that repeat, this is most likely a sensor problem - probably a solder joint or bond wire that became intermittent. Might be mitigated by measured percussive maintenance, but unlikely to be completely fixable unless you have a spare sensor board, or great SMT rework equipment, or a wire bonder, and in each case the skill to use them.....

If the exact locations change, I would suspect either strong electrical interference (powerful radio transmitters, induction heating or power distribution equipment), or a power supply component in the camera having become marginal....

Comment: Percussive maintenance: of course we all have the [necessary tool](https://i.imgur.com/kXdguEx.png) in our camera bag :)

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this answer, but I would like to first try to reproduce the issue, perhaps through application of the suggested percussive tooling.

Comment: In case someone misunderstood: vibration can temporarily fix intermittents, either by making loose parts hit together or by rubbing off oxide layers ... the old "slapping the television to make it work" trope has some basis in reality. Hammer not recommended in either case, unless used to steal a new and working television or camera from a shop window and aware of potential adverse consequences. And never for IBM typewriters.

Answer (score 1):

I use Photos software on a Macintosh for import and storage of pics, and just started having the same problems after changing from a D7000 to a D7500. Same line in the images in Photos. If I export the jpg image that Photos lets you export, the line follows with it. The line is always horizontal, but the thing is, the line is horizontal in BOTH vertical and horizontal pics. That tells me it's not originating in the camera. I shoot raw normally, and sure enough, when I export the original raw nef-image from Photos into camera raw/photoshop - no line. All good. So the problem lies in how Photos software makes its jpg from the raw somehow, not in your sensor/card.

Answer (score 0):

If your sensor has dead-by-design areas that the raw processing software does not know about, depending on the demosaicing algorithm and the used arithmetic (and the image content), such artifacts can occur, strange though that may seem.  Check the in-camera JPEG for comparison.  If it does not show similar stripes, it's likely that your raw processing software needs some crop area to be configured before attempting demosaicing.  This is usually part of the camera definition: possibly an update of the software is all that is needed.